# Create a button which loads a specific number of card components onClick similar to pagination in NextJS & Typescript

Tags: button, next.js

Below is the UI. I have already created the card component and currently, I'm using a data array (mock data) for the content in the components

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1a0E.jpg)

The following is how the card component renders with the data array through a map fuction.

```
<CardGrid
        render={(item: any) => (
          <FutureEventCard
            newEvent={item.new}
            title={item.title}
            body={item.body}
          />
        )}
        items={[
          {
            new: true,
            title: 'UI UX global summit 23',
            body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr commodo ligula eget...',
          },
          {
            new: true,
            title: 'UI UX global summit 23',
            body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr commodo ligula eget...',
          },
          {
            new: true,
            title: 'UI UX global summit 23',
            body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr commodo ligula eget...',
          },
          {
            new: true,
            title: 'UI UX global summit 23',
            body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr commodo ligula eget...',
          },
          {
            new: true,
            title: 'UI UX global summit 23',
            body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr commodo ligula eget...',
          },
        ]}
      />
```

This is what I have tried for now. I have only created a button component

```
<Button>View all</Button>
```